# Python and firebase realtime monitoring

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

please is there a way to monitor your firebase database using python so as to perform a particular task when a new element is added.
Like to constantly check for new or incoming elements into the database;to check if a new element has been added to the database.

Comment: Did you see the `listen` method in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to changes made to the specific fields of your firebase realtime database using the `listen` method of `firebase-admin`.

Here is the complete example:

```
# Importing required packages
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

# Initializing the database with URL
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/your/service.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
    'databaseURL': 'https://YOUR-DATABASE-URL-NAME-HERE.firebaseio.com/'
}) 


def listener(event):
    print(event.event_type)  # Indicates the type of the event done
    print(event.path)  # References the path of the event
    print(event.data)  # Gives the UPDATED DATA, None if deleted

    # Now, executing specific functions based on the new data(UPDATED DATA)

    if str(event.data) == 'hello':
        # /// Execute your code here ///
        print('Data updated as ', str(event.data))

    elif str(event.data) == None:
        # /// Execute your code here ///
        print('Your data has been deleted!')

    # Follow these steps

db.reference('path/to/monitor').listen(listener) # It calls the above listener method(It continuosly listens for the data changes in your database)
# Everytime the data changes, listener function will be called
```